# TTMessageController cannot set its textEditor as firstResponder

Tags: iphone, three20

I have a subclass of TTMessageController which is (CommentViewController) and I have the following mapping

```
[map from:@"tt://postDetails/(initWithPostId:)/(anotherId:)" toViewController:[PostDetailsViewController class]];
[map from:@"tt://groupBoardAddComment/(initWithPostId:)/(anotherId:)" toModalViewController:[CommentViewController class]];
```

**When I call CommentViewController from my PostDetailsViewController class**, its keyboard does not appear, **but when I call it from my other view controller class its keyboard appears**,

even if I try to force to becomeFirstResponder its textEditor in all viewWillAppear, viewDidLoad and etc. methods of my CommentViewController, still I cannot make it appear.

hope for a reply, really need help with this, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is, i call the method when user begins edit in my textfield, instead of textfield i change it to a button with a selector to call and display the CommentViewController,

Instead of this

```
- (IBAction)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(id)sender {
    CommentViewController *commentViewController = [[CommentViewController alloc] initWithPostId:self.postId groupId:self.groupId];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                initWithRootViewController:commentViewController];
    [self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
    [navigationController release];
    [commentViewController release]; 
}
```

I made a method to be called by a button as a selector

```
-(void) displayCommentView
    CommentViewController *commentViewController = [[CommentViewController alloc] initWithPostId:self.postId groupId:self.groupId];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                    initWithRootViewController:commentViewController];
    [self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
    [navigationController release];
    [commentViewController release];
```